# How to properly store CKEditor HTML input

Tags: php, mysql, json, ckeditor

Im using CKEditor to store HTML input.  Its working fine the one way.  Data goes into the database exactly as I input it.

However, when I try to retrieve it in JSON, I get all sorts of parsing errors.

Here is a simple string which screws up

```
<p>This is my text</p>

<span style="font-size:14px">More test</span>
```

The JSON gets hung up on the double quotes, and the spaces.  So I implemented this function in PHP before it gets inserted.

```
function parseline($string){
  $string = str_replace(chr(10), "//n", $string);
  $string = str_replace(chr(13), "//n", $string);
  $string = str_replace(chr(34), "'", $string);
  $string = str_replace("'","\'", $string); 
  return $string;
}
```

That line then becomes

```
<p>This is a test and more content</p>//n<span style=\'font-size:72px\'>
```

However.  This still hangs up the JSON parsing.

How do I correctly store data from CKEditor, and then how to parse it back from the database, so that it can be parsed correctly as JSON??

Ideally I want to store it properly.  And then I'll need to reverse parse the //n out to display back in the editor properly.  Because right now, if I get valid data, I still get the //n displayed in the editor as actual values.

Ive been on this for 6 hours now.  And Im tearing my hair out.

**EDIT -  Still stuck on this 22 hours later**

Here is what is going into the database

```
<p>qweqweqweqwe</p>
```

And then Im getting it like this (using Lumen/laravel)

```
$post = Post::find($id);
return json_encode($post);
```

Then in Vue Im getting that json

```
 el:'#app',
 data : {
   post: {}
},
methods: {
  getPost: function(id){
     var that = this;
     $.ajax({
     url:'post/'+id,
     dataType:'json',
     type:'GET'
    }).done(function(data){
       // Assign the data to Vue 
       that.post = JSON.parse(data);
    }).fail(function(xhr){
   });
  }
}
```

This fails, with this exception

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 175
```

And the json returned is

```
 {"uuid":"0bcb9c59-19da-4dcf-90d6-6dd53adfb449","title":"test","slug":"test","body":"<p>qweqweqweqwe</p>
 ","created_at":1519529598,"updated_at":1519534639}
```

So obviously its failing because there is an Enter key after the ending < /p >.  But I already tried removing all enter keys and all that before storing.   Replacing with new line /n. That works, but then I get //n back, and also things like style="font-size:14px;"  from CKeditor, also make it fail, because of the double quotes.

So the issue is.  Im storing the data exactly as its entered in the database.  Retrieving it properly is just most definitely not working or easy to do at all it seems.  At least as valid json.

**EDIT 3 - Completeley lost and officially stumped**

Im getting this back as json

```
 var data = {
  "uuid": "2cd2d954-233a-46d6-8111-29596262d3bc",
  "body": "<p>test<\/p>\n",
  "cover_img": "https:\/\/static.pexels.com\/photos\/170811\/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg",
  "title": "asdf",
  "slug": "asdf",
  "created_at": 1519536364,
  "updated_at": 1519538302
}
```

If i do

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

I consistently get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 66
```

Even though if you copy that exact object over to JSONLint.com, its completely valid.  Im so stumped. The most stumped I think I have ever been on any issue in my entire career.  Which is wierd, because it seems like it would be such an easy bug to find.

Comment: Im more looking for a generic answer.  So I can have the knowledge for the future.  And apply it to any type of HTML input/output via JSON.  Sure...I can use the CKeditor save, but thats not what Im trying to do

Comment: What does `"//n"` mean, what should it do?

Comment: Why are you using JSON and not leave the text as it is? What code do you use to store and retrieve the data?

Comment: Because Im using VueJS as my front end.  So I work with JSON data strictly

Comment: @KyleK Store it as-is. Provide it to Vue by doing `json_encode($html)`. Don't otherwise touch it, at all.

Comment: imo, Checkout the [JSON Constants that encode special characters for use with jsan_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php). see an example of use: [Eval.in - encoded html as JSON (validated)](https://eval.in/962294)

Comment: @ceejayoz  THats exactly what Im doing.

Comment: @KyleK Then you're going to need to show us a) sample JSON you're sending to Vue and b) how Vue parses and handles that response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a CKEditor instance named `editor1`, get CKEditor data, construct an object with it, stringify it and send it to database without PHP manipulation (`JSON.stringify` will take care of escaping characters):

```
JSON.stringify({'ckdata': editor1.getData()})
```

Retrieve data from database as text  without PHP manipulation and parse it as JSON object:

```
JSON.parse(databasedata).ckdata;
```

EDIT: ceejayoz gave a better answer, since data is stored unmodified in database

Answer (score 0):

Store it directly as HTML in the database. Don't modify, tweak, or otherwise screw with it at all - what's in the database should be exactly what the user submitted. <sup><sub>(Stuff like XSS protection, parsing short codes, etc. should be done *on display*, so you can adjust your algorithms while still having the original HTML to work with.)</sub></sup>

Provide it to Vue by running it through `json_encode`, which will escape it correctly:

```
$response = ['html' => $html];

return json_encode($response);
```

(You can also just do `json_encode($html)`, which will return a JS-friendly string instead of a JSON object. Vue'll be happy with that, too.)

The resulting JSON will be:

```
{"html":"<p>This is my text<\/p>\n\n<span style=\"font-size:14px\">More test<\/span>"}
```

which Vue will be just fine with when you `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: yeah this is already what Im doing.  So I dont get what Im doing wrong.  Ill edit my post with an example...

Comment: @KyleK I think you're double-decoding things. Laravel sends data in `application/json` content type, which I'd bet Vue's HTTP request library (are you using Axios?) automatically decodes. Try just using `data` **without** the `JSON.parse`. Do a `console.log` on the response - I'll bet the response data is already in JS-friendly object form.